# Finding the number of teams

Tags: arithmetic

I played in a online tournament of a game of some sorts, and I want to know how many teams they were.

I have the following informations :

- The team who finished in first place were on the Top 0.001%
- The team who finished in 9501th place were on the Top 0.287%
- The team who finished in 10000th place were on the Top 0.302%

Thank you math genius that you are!

Answer (score 3):

> The team who finished in 10000th place were on the Top 0.302%

In other words **10,000** teams make up **0.302%** of the entire pool.

Then **20,000** teams make up **0.604%** (since $2*10,000=20,000$ and $2*0.302\% = 0.604\%$)
and  **30,000** teams make up **0.906%** (since $3*10,000=30,000$ and $3*0.302\% = 0.906\%$)
...
and  **3,310,000** teams make up **100%** (since $331*10,000 = 3,310,000$ and $331*0.302\% \approx 100\%$)

Comment: Thanks!! Bonus question, was that ways about our rank in we were in the 38% ?

Comment: try using this template to figure out the solution and report back where it gets you